# asp.Net newbie help me

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reverse

I'm trying to get into the world of asp.NET and I'm trying out some stuff.

Am I way off??

```
     <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtoriginal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnCount" runat="server" Text="reverse" 
        onclick="btnCount_Click" />

    <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server"></asp:Label>

</form>
```

so this is that part im havin trouble with

```
    protected void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        lblAnswer.Text = txtoriginal.Text;

        stroriginalText = txtoriginal.Text;
        strReverse = stroriginalText.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(strReverse);
        lblAnswer.Text = strReverse;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? are you missing `ToString()` on your char array?

Comment: Note the fallacy of reversing strings in that way: [http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx](OMG Ponies!!! (Aka Humanity: Epic Fail)) ... Search for `like you to write some code to reverse a string`

Comment: I wish I could say what I am missing.. I've tried some different solutions but I must be missing something, can't see what it is though

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a new `string` from the `char[]`:

```
char[] chars = txtoriginal.Text.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(chars);
blAnswer.Text = new string(chars);
```

But note that reversing a string isn't the same as reversing a sequence of characters.

See: 
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/

[image]

[image]

Comment: @NoOne: credit goes to Jon Skeet, it's from his blog linked above.

Answer (score 1):

you can write an extension method for this

```
public static string Reverse(this String s )
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return new string( charArray );
}
```

and call it like this

```
lblAnswer.Text = txtoriginal.Text.Reverse();
```

Comment: So the answer why it didn't work is because it was no extension method? ;-)

Comment: ofcourse not. you had already answered, so i though give it a bit of twist.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string Str, Revstr = "";                
     str=(txtoriginal.Text);
       for (int i = Str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
             Revstr = Revstr + Str[i];
        }
        lblAnswer.Text= Revstr;
  }
```

i think this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
str = string.Join("", str.Reverse());
```

so your code becomes:

```
lblAnswer.Text = string.Join("",txtoriginal.Text.Reverse());
```

Of course if you have included Linq namespace

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can solve this when you create a new string from char[]. Something like this:

```
char[] strChars = txtOriginal.Text.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(strChars);
blAnswer.Text = new string(strChars);
```

Regards.